# How can I implement my security policy in java program itself

Tags: java, rmi

I am really new in java-RMI and developed a small application on it.But to run my server and client I need to execute-
Java -Djava.security.policy=client.policy

So what should I do to ommite '-Djava.security.policy=client.policy' this command? Or is there any way to implement the security policy in java program?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Omiit it unless you plan on using the codebase feature.

Answer (score -1):

Policy file is required in RMI Application so that client can connect to the remote server.you also need to implement the securityManager in the client as well as in the Server. this security manager will allow you to connect to any rmi remote host to which client is intended to connect.I think policy file cannot be ommitted in RMI. it is required.

Comment: Completely incorrect. You can write entire RMI applications without security managers or policy files. They're only needed when you use the codebase feature.